# Set priority between different versions of Xcode

Tags: xcode, applescript

In AppleScript script I have command `tell application "Xcode"` which I want to use Xcode 3, while it uses Xcode 4 now.

How to specify the Xcode version in  `tell application` command or to set priority between different Xcode versions for `tell application` command.

Don't advise `xcode-select`: it sets priority between Xcode versions only for xcode console tools.

**UPDATE**

As @Red_Menace metioned we can use path to `.app` file or id of the application. Please say if there is a better solution (e.g. set priority to access Xcode 3 by name `"Xcode"`).

Comment: Can you simply specify the fully-qualified path. Like `tell application "/Xcode4/Xcode"` vs, `tell application "/Xcode3/Xcode"`?

Comment: I was using paths. Right now I use IDs. But I think there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use application paths or IDs (the bundle identifier) in the tell statement, for example

```
tell application "/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app"
       -- or --
tell application id "com.apple.Xcode" -- Xcode 3
       -- or --
tell application id "com.apple.dt.Xcode" -- Xcode 4
```

Comment: Yes. I was using `"/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app"` before. Right now I am using IDs. But I'm interested if there is a better solution.

Comment: Those are the options that are built-in, but you can also do something like set a variable to the ID of what is available, checking for Xcode 3 first (or whatever).  A variable can also be used in a tell statement, you just need to surround it with a 'using terms from' statement so that the editor knows what application to use.